# Rails override attribute using his getter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, attributes, getter-setter

I have a `price` attribute in my model.

Can I use attribute-getter, which is named just like the attribute

```
def price
   ... logic logic ..
   return something
end
```

in order to override the attribute itself ?

Currently it doesn't work. If I call `model.price` it works, but when it somes to saving the object via `model.save`, it stores the default value.

Can it be done in a painless way, or should I make a `before_save` callback?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set a value in Ruby you access the setter method. If you want to override the setter you have to do something like this:

```
def price=(_price)
  # do some logic
  write_attribute(:price, _price)
end
```

This is of course a discussion point. Sometimes you can better use a callback. Something like this:

```
before_save :format_price

private

def format_price
  # Do some logic, for example make it cents.
  self.price = price * 100
end
```

Comment: The first solution is going to cause an infinite loop.  `def price` is defining `self.price`.

Comment: Forgot to mention - I dont have a setter for the price, becase price is calculater internally in the model, based on the other attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Since you seem to want the "real" value stored in the database, what you probably want to do is modify the setter.  This way the actual value is stored, and the `price` getter can just return it unmodified.

You can do this via the lower level `write_attribute` method.  Something like:

```
def price=(value)
  # logic logic
  self.write_attribute(:price, value)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manipulate the attribute's value right before it's saved then using a callback would be a better way, since this is what callbacks are for.

Comment: This isn't necessarily true, as it would mean he couldn't see the modified value on the record before saving it.

Comment: Yes it isn't always true. Depends on the case.